# Best way to store video content for later playback in Unity?

Tags: video-streaming, virtual-reality, google-cardboard, video-player

I'm currently working on a Unity app for educational purposes. It should be able to playback 3D panoramic content on-demand by android devices. In this stage, we are defining the software architecture and production roadmap and a BIG question had arrived.

We are going to use the unity VideoPlayer to playback the content from an external HTTP source utilizing the built-in method of streaming called AFAIK "Progressive Streaming". But we don't know which is the best technology solution to store the videos on the web. Like, dedicated server with a SQL DTB, or a Google Cloud/AWS/Azure web services like a bucket. Or a hybrid like a DB on a dedicated server with Key - URL of each video, and the videos stored on a bucket on the web. The most important thing here is to consider horizontal scalability, we don't know how many requests to the content are going to be needed, but we are talking about +10k users.

Any, and I mean ANY idea/help it's welcome.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I'd look at a CDN option unless your app is going to be very narrowly locally released. The latency globally kills streaming pretty badly.

Comment: Hey Gabe! Thank you for the replay :D. Yes, we are looking at those options too. But the fact is that we are first going to do market validation with a soft launch in our region, LATAM, we are from Argentina. Talking about "best" ways to store video content, I find that the Unity VideoPlayer only stream content from absolute URLs on static servers. Do you know if GCS or AWS provide that kind of storage?

Comment: You can host static assets on GCS (Google Cloud Storage) yeah. If you're regional on a soft launch, that should work for you. I'm fairly sure you could do the same on S3, but I don't have a lot of experience with AWS. :)

Comment: You just made my day hehe. I will start right away with GCS testing. :D